# How to simplify the complex expression of the Fourier series for a square wave?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series

I'm trying to find the expression of the fourier series (using complex numbers) for the following odd squarewave function with period T:

$V(t) = V_0$  for $0<t<T/2$

$V(t) = -V_0$ for $T/2<t<T$

I've come this far :

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi*j}\sum_{n=-\infty,n=odd}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e^{jn\omega t}$$

The book where I got this exercise from gives the answer as:

$$\frac{4V_0}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty,n=odd}^\infty \frac{sin n\omega t}{n}$$

My question is how to go from my expression to the book's answer.

Here's what I've tried:

I noticed the $j$ was gone on both sides and the $2$ became a $4$, so I thought about splitting $\frac{2V_0}{\pi*j}$ into $\frac{2}{j}$ and $\frac{V_0}{\pi}$ and then squaring $\frac{2}{j}$ to get $-4$ which would give $-\frac{4V_0}{\pi}$.

Then, $e^{jn\omega t}$ can be written as $cos(n\omega t)+jsin(n\omega t)$ and $cos(n\omega t)$ disappears because we are dealing with an odd function.

The book also suggests using the properties: $sin(\theta)=-sin(-\theta)$ and $cos(\theta)=cos(-\theta)$ which, if I understand correctly, let us write the complex number as $cos(-n\omega t)-jsin(-n\omega t)$. In that case, we would be left with $-jsin(-n\omega t)$.

However, no matter how I try to simplify the expression after that, I'm always left with the $j$ and a minus sign.

Comment: Try converting $\frac{2 j V_o}{\pi n} e^{-j n t w}-\frac{2 j V_o}{\pi n} e^{j n t w}$ into trigonometric form.

Comment: Since $$\frac{2 i V_o}{\pi n} \left(e^{-j n t w}-e^{j n t w}\right)=\frac{2 j V_o}{\pi n} ((\cos(n t w)-j \sin(n t w))-(\cos(n t w)+j \sin(n t w)))=\frac{2 j V_o}{\pi n} (-j \sin (n t w)-j \sin (n t w))=\frac{4 V_o}{\pi n} \sin(n t w)$$ the resulting sum over the $\sin$ terms should start at $n=1$, not $n=-\infty$, and the final result can be evaluated as $$\frac{4 V_0}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sin((2 n-1) \omega t)}{2 n-1}.$$

Comment: @Steven Clark Ok, but where did you get this expression from: $\frac{2 j V_o}{\pi n} e^{-j n t w}-\frac{2 j V_o}{\pi n} e^{j n t w}$ ?

Comment: It's the term of the right-side of $$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi j}\sum\limits_{\substack{n=-\infty \\ n\, odd}}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e^{jn\omega t}=\frac{2 j V_0}{\pi}\sum\limits_{\substack{n=1 \\ n\, odd}}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} e^{-j n \omega t}-\frac{1}{n} e^{j n \omega t}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help @Steven Clark. I figured it out with some more help from a math professor.

I finally have some time to share the full steps here for anyone interested:

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi*j}\sum_{n=-\infty,n=odd}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e^{jn\omega t}$$

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}\frac{1}{j}\sum_{n=-\infty,n=odd}^\infty \frac{1}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+j\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)$$

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty,n=odd}^\infty -\frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)$$

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}[\sum_{n=-\infty,n=odd}^{-1} -\frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)+\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} -\frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)]$$

Substituting n for -n in the first sum:

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}[\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} -\frac{j}{-n}cos(-n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{-n}sin(-n\omega_0t)+\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} -\frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)]$$

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}[\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} \frac{j}{n}cos(-n\omega_0t)-\frac{1}{n}sin(-n\omega_0t)+\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} -\frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)]$$

Now, using sin(θ)=−sin(−θ) and cos(θ)=cos(−θ):

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}[\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} \frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)+\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} -\frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)]$$

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} [\frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)-\frac{j}{n}cos(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)]$$

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} [\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)]$$

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} [\frac{2}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)]$$

$$V(t)=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}*2\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} [\frac{1}{n}sin(n\omega_0t)]$$

Finally, we get the right answer:

$$V(t)=\frac{4V_0}{\pi}\sum_{n=1,n=odd}^{\infty} \frac{sin(n\omega_0t)}{n}$$

Note: there is an error in the book's answer, the sum should not start from $-\infty$ but rather from $1$.